# How to add "N" days to $smarty.now?

Tags: php, date, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I have a parameter in my page called 'priceValidUntil', for this parameter I have the line:

```
<meta itemprop="priceValidUntil" content="{$smarty.now|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}">
```

I want to add to the `$smarty.now` value 15 days, so I've added this:

```
 <meta itemprop="priceValidUntil" content="{$smarty.now|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' + 15 }">
```

The output is this:

```
 <meta itemprop="priceValidUntil" content="2024-04-27 23:04:05">
```

I want:

```
<meta itemprop="priceValidUntil" content="2019-05-12 23:04:05">
```

How can I add days instead of years?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Method 1

According to [this link](https://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=64359), it seems you might be able to do so, maybe by adding:

```
 {$smarty.now+24*60*60*15|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}
```

to your `content` attribute.

- In the numbers, <kbd>24</kbd> is hours, one of <kbd>60</kbd> stands for minutes and the other <kbd>60</kbd> stands for seconds, times by <kbd>15</kbd> days, is to calculate the seconds that you wish to add to `$smarty.now` variable.
- Then, your code may look like:

  ```
  <meta itemprop="priceValidUntil" content="{$smarty.now+15*24*60*60|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}">
  ```

#### Method 2

You might simply try this:

```
{"+15 days"|strtotime|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}
```

Then, your code might look like:

```
<meta itemprop="priceValidUntil" content="{$smarty.now+1296000|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}">
```

Comment: hi,thanks - but i'm getting wrong output : <meta itemprop="priceValidUntil" content="1598985267">

Comment: you are the best :)  this is the right code: ** <meta itemprop="priceValidUntil" content="{"+15 days"|strtotime|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}"> **

Answer (score 0):

Use both methods to try which one fits better to you.
For example in Prestashop 1.6.x is OK to use method 2, without errors.